# c# DataGridView get Cells Value from Selected Row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

how do I made the proper syntax of this `foreach` loop. I want to get every cell value from row selected.
I already set the selection mode to `FullRowSelect`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      foreach (//datagrid cell in current_selected_row) <--- proper Syntax condition
      {
           if(cell != null)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find current row this way:

```
var row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
```

Then having current row you can find cell values in one of these ways

```
row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(cell =>
   {
       MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", cell.Value));
   });
```

That is equivalent to :

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", cell.Value));
}
```

Or this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", row.Cells[i].Value));
}
```

Comment: WOw thank you. i use the foreach but what does the line ''cell =>'' means.

Comment: but when im trying to filter it to if cell.value.ToString() != null. it throws System.NullReferenceException. Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.